# Error messages and console logs in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, electron

How do you view error messages and console logs in Electron during development? Also, is it possible for the logs to be written directly into a file?

---

**Edit:** Kind of like the errors and console logs displayed by Chrome's dev tools:
[image: Screenshot of Chrome's dev tools]
Except in Electron rather than Chrome.

Comment: what is means of logs in Electron?

Comment: On client side you can not maintain log in file but on sever side you can write log in file as per my knowledge.

Comment: @ManeeshSingh it's a client-side application. It's fine if I can't write the logs to a file, but is it possible to view them at all?

Comment: yes you can see all log whatever you written in console.log by using chrome dev tools or in  Mozila you have to install "firebug" add on. after that 
1: you can inspect element.
2: open console.

Comment: @ManeeshSingh sorry if I'm not being clear, I am not using a web browser. I'm creating a desktop app in Electron and I need to view the logs as my app is running *in* Electron.

Comment: Dear Oztaco  do not say sorry. It is not your mistake.I have not have any experience of Electron development.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On your BrowserWindow call the function `openDevTools()` this will open the same dev tools you find in Chrome. I wrote about this on my blog at http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/debugging-renderer-process-in-electron/.

Here is a simple main.js file that includes openDevTools:

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin')  
    app.quit();
});

app.on('ready', function() {    
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});  
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });  
});
```

You can also access this via a renderer process using the remote module. For the apps I have been tinkering with I bind the function `toggleDevTools` to F12. Something like this:

```
  var remote = require('remote');           
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {  
    if (e.keyCode === 123) { // F12
      var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
      window.toggleDevTools();         
    }
  });
```

Note that I have only tested the above with Electron in Windows. I am assuming the Linux and Mac versions work the same. If you are running Mac or Linux please let me know if they do not.

Comment: Also, for logging to a file, you can also use a typical logging package like Winston or Bunyan.

Comment: Just to confirm that the function `openDevTools()` works fine on Mac

Comment: re:@Josh - any example of how to connect `winston` to override Electron's `console`?

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit old, but for your question on if you can write the renderer logs (the `console.log` statements in your browser javascript) to a file - yes you can.  Just run electron with the command line arguments `--log-file=FILEPATH` and `--enable-logging`. (**Note, `FILEPATH` should be an absolute filepath, and the parent directory in the path should exist - electron will not create the parent directory for you if it doesn't exist.**) If you start electron like this, the `console.log` statements from the browser will be written to `FILEPATH`. (Read more about those command line arguments [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/command-line-switches.md#--enable-loggingfile))

For example, this is what a normal `package.json` looks like for an electron app:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Just an app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest"
  }
}
```

Change it to:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Just an app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron . --log-file=C:/Users/you/Documents/myfile.txt --enable-logging"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest"
  }
}
```

(modify that path to suit your operating system.) Now run your electron app via `npm start` like normal, and the browser's console logs will be saved to the file `C:/Users/you/Documents/myfile.txt`

As a side note - this will *not* work if electron is bundled into an exe via a utility like `electron-packager` or `electron-builder`; the `start` script in `package.json` will be ignored when the exe is run, so the command line params would not get passed when starting electron. As an alternative, you can add electron command line parameters programmatically to your app at the top of `main.js` (before the app loads):

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('log-file', logfile);
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-logging');
```

([Documentation showing how to do this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches))

Comment: Very helpful thanks! I found that my electron was `outdated` and was complaining that it didn't understand what was enable-logging. All I did was `update electron to the latest version`, mine got updated to v21 and this functionality works.

Comment: so glad it works for you. I had a lot of headache over figuring out electron logging, but once you get it going, it will save you so much time debugging. By the way,  if you want to log your main process output (i.e. `console.log` statements in `main.js`) to a logfile, you might look into a package called `electron-log` https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log . I was weary to use this at first as I didn't want anymore npm packages, but it's very lightweight and it works well. Just thought I would pass along

Comment: @bikz Do you know if there is any way to log only console.error messages to the log file?

Comment: @Thomas I believe `electron-log` should do what you want https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log It supports various log levels, and you could set log level to error. I threw together a little example: https://github.com/bkuz114/electron-examples/tree/main/log_files . It's a fully working electron app which generates logfiles (but only from console.error); checkout or replicate the code then run `npm install && npm start` to run the app. Alternatively, if you just want to see `main.js` (which handles the logging): https://github.com/bkuz114/electron-examples/blob/main/log_files/main.js

Comment: @Thomas Reading back over the answer you were replying to, I realize now you might have been wondering how to modify that specific example only (logging renderer logs using electron command line switches). If so, you might take a look at the electron switch `--log-level` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches#--log-leveln . electron's documentation wants you to read some Chrome source code to figure out how to use this switch, but might be worth digging in if you don't want to bring an extra npm package into your project

Comment: After looking back over the example I posted on github, it appears that my example only limits logs to `console.error` within the *main* process; in renderer process, it is still displaying all console logs, unfortunately. I attempted to use electron command line switches to fix this, but was unable to. That said, I am out of practice with electron, so maybe someone with fresher eyes is better suited to figure this out. Apologies that I was not able to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is a bit outdated today, but almost perfect.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600}); 
mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
```

It opens dev tools automatically when app is running in electron.
I am using Electron on Windows

Source https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging